# How could go through two tags for processing ec2 instances

Tags: python, tags

Dear friends and gurus here:

I am working on a python script to power off/on instances based on two tag values. I have two tags assigned to each ec2 instances. One is "schedule_name" tag which defines what schedule it should be powered off/on, the other is "skip_shutdown" tag which should remove that instance from shutdown schedule and reset its value to "no". (this works as a temporary switch for un-Normal reason not powering it off)

I got trapped here by how to use stacked "tag['key']

here is my code

```
for instance in instances:

        for tag in instance.tags:

            if tag['Key'] == 'Schedule_Name':
                
                    if tag['Value'] == 'App' and current_time == app_off.get(current_dayoftheweek):

                        if tag['Key'] == 'skip_shutdown':
                            if tag['Value'] == 'yes':
                                # reset the tag value to "no" for this tag
                            
                            if tag['Value'] == 'no':
                                # add this instance to stopInstances variable to stop it.
                                    stopInstances.append(instance.id)

                        pass
                    pass
```

Comment: you should rather use `if ... elif ...` instead of nested `if ... if..` And you should assign values it external variables - and after `for`-loop check if both values are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for`-loop you should only get values and assing to variables.

And after `for`-loop you should use both variables to on/off

```
for instance in instances:

    # - before loop `for tag`-       

    Schedule_Name = None
    skip_shutdown = None

    # - loop `for tag`-       
    
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Schedule_Name':
            Schedule_Name = tag['Value']
        elif tag['Key'] == 'skip_shutdown':
            skip_shutdown = tag['Value']
            
    # - after loop `for tag`-       
    
    if Schedule_Name == 'App' and current_time == app_off.get(current_dayoftheweek):
        if skip_shutdown == 'yes':
            # reset the tag value to "no" for this tag
        elif tag['Value'] == 'no':
            # add this instance to stopInstances variable to stop it.
            stopInstances.append(instance.id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. I really appreciate it. I will implement your method now.

Comment: I got this error when running it in lambda function: "esponse
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': expected an indented block (lambda_function.py, line 153)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 153\n                elif tag['Value'] == 'no':\n"
  ]
}

Comment: `
        # - after loop `for tag`-     Check which instance need to be off  
    
        if Schedule_Name == 'App' and current_time == app_off.get(current_dayoftheweek):
            if skip_shutdown == 'yes':
                # reset the tag value to "no" for this tag
            elif tag['Value'] == 'no':
                # add this instance to stopInstances variable to stop it.
                stopInstances.append(instance.id)
        pass`

Comment: I don't know how to format my code in comments. How could I format my code ?

Comment: `       # - after loop `for tag`-     Check which instance need to be off  
    
        if Schedule_Name == 'App' and current_time == app_off.get(current_dayoftheweek):
            if skip_shutdown == 'yes':
                # reset the tag value to "no" for this tag
            elif tag['Value'] == 'no':
                # add this instance to stopInstances variable to stop it.
                stopInstances.append(instance.id)
        pass  `

Comment: you can't format code in comment - if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page. You will have more space for code and description, and more people may see it - so more people may help you. Error `Syntax error` and `expected an indented block` may mean you have wrong indentations.

Comment: Thank you, Furas, I have made some progress but create another issue. I will open a new question and hope you can take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578300/my-else-statement-got-excuted-even-when-the-condition-satisfies-if-statement